# Set ActionView for MenuItem to be shown in menu list

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I'm using:

```
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

Is it possible to make working next combination:

```
  <item
      android:id="@+id/user"
      app:actionLayout="@layout/user_info_menu_layout"
      android:enabled="false"
      android:title="@string/User"
      app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I'm trying to get for free similar menu for Twitter application.

Note:

The problem is `showAsAction="never"` and `actionLayout`. As soon as I change `never` to `always` I see custom view in toolbar.

Note 2:

Calling `setActionView(R.layout.user_info_menu_layout)` doesn't work also

Comment: If you want to see the view, why use "never"?

Comment: @KristyWelsh I don't want to see it always. Since doesn't have drawer yet, it is temporary fix for showing user name and profile picture

Comment: `actionLayout` also need name space `app`, `app:actionLayout=`

Comment: Updated question, namespace doesn't help as well calling from code `setActionView` for `item`